# Why was my comment deleted, and this this replacement comment okay?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I'd left a "lead by example" comment addressed to the user who wrote an [extended comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32654/what-would-happen-if-a-sun-like-star-were-to-consume-a-jupiter-like-planet#comment60259_32654) about why they'd chosen to immediately close [What would happen if a Sun-like star were to consume a Jupiter-like planet?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32654/7982) rather than ask for clarification or propose an edit, and a comment to another user who [suggests](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32654/what-would-happen-if-a-sun-like-star-were-to-consume-a-jupiter-like-planet#comment60262_32654) the question "falls under the hypothetical scenarios rule". (There is no such "rule", we only have suggested guidelines for on-topic-ness which is subjective and needs to be addressed on a case-by-case basis)

As I see it, on a site with a low question rate, there's no benefit at all to insta-closing a good question that simply needs a bit of work. "Leading by example" means showing a new user, posting their first question, the best way to improve it by making an edit. Having an example is likely much easier for a new Stack Exchange user to understand than to simply close and point to help.

Yes, that was the old way, but it's far less welcoming than being helpful.

**Question:** Why was my comment deleted, and this this replacement comment okay?

My new comment is

> I've voted to leave this question open. Rather than voting to close, I've made an edit to improve the question. Closing would have blocked anyone from answering further. There were 4 vtc votes; one more vote would have instantly blocked [this excellent, thorough and authoritative answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32695/7982) from being posted!

Luckily at least one of the vtc were retracted, possibly in response to my two (now deleted) requests for vtc retraction. This likely facilitated @RobJeffries opportunity to post the answer.

I'm pretty sure my way is better in these cases (helpful comments and exemplary edits versus insta-closing) and I think facilitating the linked answer is evidence of this, *so I'm interested to understand what was delete-worthy in my comment, and how could I have composed it differently to encourage keeping good questions open.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original comment was seen as being too confrontational, and I could see where they were coming from. The new one looks fine.

Comment: okay, I'll (continue to) work on that, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @uhoh The part that troubled the user was "Let's stop insta-closing everything". They read it as targeting them specifically as being malicious. In my opinion, your new comment avoids this impression, which is why it's better.

Comment: Oh, seeing it now, yes I concur.